# Pasting values of a list to get sum values of columns

Tags: r

I would like to create a sum of different columns. There I have a for loop that creates a name of a column and the fetches the sum.

With dummy data is like this:

```
row1 <- c(1,2,3)
row2 <- c(23,3,4)

df <- data.frame(row1, row2)
```

I want to create something like this:\

```
list <- c("row1", "row2")

for (i in 1:2){

  name <- list[i]
  var <- paste0("df$", name)

  x <- sum(var)
  print(x)

}
```

This however throws the following error:

```
Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Any thoughts where I go wrong

Comment: The more standard way is to use subsetting, and `colSums`. ie `lst <-c("row1", "row2") ;colSums(dat[lst])` (ps. i changed `df` and `list`  from your example to `dat` and `lst`, respectively, as they are both R function names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any way to convert, for example, the string `'df$row1'` into a variable `df$row1` with the meaning you want.  But instead you can simply access the columns of `df` directly, using the names from that data frame, with R's list naming syntax.  The following one liner will print out the sums of each column name which appears in the `list` vector.

```
sapply(list, function(x) print(sum(df[[x]])))
```

**Output:**

```
[1] 6
[1] 30
row1 row2
   6   30
```